# ggplot returns a stacked barplot instead of a seperated barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a barplot to show the difference in IAT results between men and women when given one of four treatments (using R). I found some code online that resulted in something similar to what I want:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data = visits, aes(x = frequency, y = percent, fill = category)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
 xlab("Frequency of Father Visits") + ylab("Percent of Children") + 
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Which results in this graph:

[image]

But when I used this code for my data:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = treatment, y = IAT_D, fill = gender)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
xlab("Treatment") + ylab("D-score")
```

I got something very different:

[image]

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Gender is a dummy variable consisting of only 1 and 2, so I don't know why it's scaling this variable. Also, I want the light blue and the dark blue bins next to each other, instead of stacked like this (just like the example graph). Does it maybe have anything to do with the fact that the D-scores range from -1 to 1?

I hope I'm making sense, I'm very new to R and I don't have a programming background.

Comment: try `fill = factor(gender)`. but please include some example data otherwise it is hard to help you. Furthermore use `geom_col()` in cases of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. this is now the recommended way.

Comment: Make sure `treatment` and `gender` are factors.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I should have explained what my variables are. dat is my dataset, gender is a dummy (0 or 1), treatment is numeric (1, 2, 3, or 4) and IAT_D is also numeric (ranging from -0.8 to 1.06. So you were right in factoring my variables, but now I got this: https://imgur.com/a/ejhB0L2

Comment: Do you have multiple males/females per treatment?  If so, you are plotting the value for each individual so have multiple bars at each gender/treatment. Some of these individuals appear to have a negative value of y, so you are getting bars in both positive and negative directions.

Comment: @aosmith Ah right, I have 72 males and 110 females. I thought it would automatically take the D-score mean of the men / women per treatment. I guess I need to tell R to use the means then.